# make a rectangle zero in opencv::Mat without loop

Tags: c++, opencv

what's the efficient way to make a special block of opencv::Mat zero? (without loop)

```
Mat freq;

// Set some frequencies to 0
for (int y=0; y<freq.rows; y++)
{
    for (int x=Start; x<freq.cols; x++)
    {
        if (x>Start || y>Start)
            freq.at<double>(y,x) = 0.0;
    }
}
// Set some frequencies to 0
for (int y=Start; y<freq.rows; y++)
{
    for (int x=0; x<freq.cols; x++)
    {
        freq.at<double>(y,x) = 0.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try below code

```
Mat src;
Mat roi  = src(Rect(x,y,width,height)); // Set Roi
roi.setTo(0); // Set all pixel to 0 on both src and roi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a zero matrix. [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-zeros) is the link. You can make your entire matrix zero or create a smaller zero matrix and assign it to desired part of the original matrix.